# How to set style and template for DataGridRow on custom DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom DataGrid element. Stle and template of this element described in Theme.xml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
     <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                 <!-- ... -->
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

How do i specify template for DataGridRow specially for my custom DataGrid.
Something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border BorderThickness="3">
                    <DataGridCellsPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

litterary changing nothing.

Setting `x:Key` value for DataGridRow style and then usining it in my custom datagrid style with `Setter Property` changing nothing too.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `RowStyle` property, either in the `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        ...
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                ...
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...or on the `MyDataGrid` element:

```
<local:MyDataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            ...
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</local:MyDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a named datagrid row style in your resources:

```
<Style x:Key="specialCursorGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">           
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam"/>
</Style>
```

Then apply it to the grid using the name:

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource specialCursorGridRowStyle}">
</DataGrid>
```